# How to add the same button that was clicked into a list table?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I created buttons that show a certain gif in a modal, and in the modal there is an add to list button. I created an on click function that creates a new row that holds a completed and deleted button. Under List Items I want the the same button that was clicked on to appear with the same features. So if I clicked the chest button then that same chest button will appear with the same modal showing. Any help will be great, here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpRVW

HTML Table

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="addedList">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"><h2 id="titleName"></h2></th>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>List Items</td>
          <td class="complete">Completed</td>
          <td class="delete">Delete</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
   </div>
```

jQuery Function

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var exerciseTd = $("<td>").append();
      var completeBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-info").append("Completed");
      var completeTd = $("<td>").append(completeBtn);
      var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("Delete");
      var deleteTd = $("<td>").append(deleteBtn);

    //Appending new row and delete button to table body
    newRow.append(exerciseTd).append(completeTd).append(deleteTd);
    $("tbody").append(newRow);
    });
```

Comment: So you want the "same button" like "Chest" to be on the new row AND in the modal? also, do you wan the button in the row to open the modal too? BTW the delete button can be ` $('.table').on('click' , '.btn.btn-danger' , function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});`

Comment: Yes I just want the same to be on the new row and I want the button on the row to open the modal. I used the table click function and appended a new button called exercise that shows the gif, but when I click on another button the modal of the button that was clicked shows. So if I add the chest button to the list the bench press modal shows, however if I add or click the legs button the squatting gif shows and removes the chest gif. Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQpRVW

Answer (score 1):

I don't familiar with bootstrap but for delete btn click you can use something like

```
$('.table').on('click' , '.btn.btn-danger' , function(){
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZEzMr)

up to your comments you can pass the name of your clicked button to your modal by using data attribute .. for example .. if you click on the Chest try to set a data-listitem="Chest" to your modal and in #add click event get this data using .attr('data-listitem') and then append it like other buttons

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#chest").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Bench Press");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='https://45.media.tumblr.com/860edb05e3f8b0bf9b4313a819e87699/tumblr_mi2ud72e931qet17vo1_400.gif'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });

    $("#legs").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Squat");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='http://i.imgur.com/89ZQmzf.gif'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });

    $("#shld").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Shoulder Press");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='http://i0.wp.com/thegaysian.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/b001.gif?resize=420%2C420'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });

    $("#bi").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Incline Dumbbell Bicep Curl");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/8-05-2015/OZGZTL.gif'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });

    $("#tri").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Tricep Dips");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='https://45.media.tumblr.com/a731186fc986346bf6e2b96225e5f1f3/tumblr_njhocrvEo91six5o1o1_500.gif'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });


    $("#abs").on("click", function() {
       $("h4").html("Standing Ab Twist");
        $("p").html("<img id='yo' src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b2/9c/0e/b29c0e0eb56db9cb3451625c13a00766.jpg'>");
        $("#myModal").attr('data-listitem' , $(this).attr('id')).modal("show");
    });




    $("#add").on("click", function() {
      var listitemdata = $(this).closest('.modal').attr('data-listitem');
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var exerciseTd = $("<td>").addClass("btn btn-primary").append(listitemdata);
      var completeBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-info").append("Completed");
      var completeTd = $("<td>").append(completeBtn);
      var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("Delete");
      var deleteTd = $("<td>").append(deleteBtn);

    //Appending new row and delete button to table body
    newRow.append(exerciseTd).append(completeTd).append(deleteTd);
    $("tbody").append(newRow);
    });
$('.table').on('click' , '.btn.btn-primary' , function(){
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPwKVq)

> **Note:** $(this).attr('id') will give you the id of the element you can change it to $(this).text() to give you the content of this
>   element

Comment: @morizvi23 you can pass the name of your clicked button to your modal by using data attribute .. for example .. if you click on the Chest try to set a data-listitem="Chest" to your modal  and in #add click event get this data using    .attr('data-listitem')  and then append it like other buttons

Comment: This is great, there is just another bug when you click on different buttons after adding one to the list item. So if I add the chest button to the list item the bench press modal shows, however if I click on any other button, say like legs, the chest modal gets removed and the modal of the legs button shows. I want whatever button that was added to show the corresponding modal regardless if other buttons were clicked or added after. Hopefully this makes sense and thanks again for your help you have been really great.

Comment: Yes Thanks both answers helped me out

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but it works (see the comments for explanation) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxRzJQ
Basically, it puts the btn ID and btn text of the selected exercise in a variable, then adds these attr to the button. The button then clicks the associated exercise.

```
 // globals 
 var currentBtn
 var currentBtnTxt

 //assign the var on each click
  $("#chest").on("click", function() {
  currentBtn = $(this).attr('id')
  currentBtnTxt = $(this).text() .. .

  //adds the button

  var modalBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-info exbtn ").attr("data-type", currentBtn).append(currentBtnTxt)
  var exerciseTd = $("<td>").append(modalBtn);
  //delete row
 $('.table').on('click' , '.btn.btn-danger' , function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
 //show modal from list btn
  $('.table').on('click' , '.exbtn' , function(){
   var type = $(this).data('type')
    //hide the add to list button
     $("#add").hide()
    $("#"+type).click()
});
```

Also, I added a "cancel" button to the modal

```
  //this will reset the add to list button when the modal closes
     $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $("#add").show()
 })
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! Sorry to be a pain still new to jquery, anyway to remove the add list button of the modal once it is added to the table? I don't want the user to add the button from the table.

Comment: Ok, updated it to do that, but again, this is not ideal - I would redesign from the start, but this will get your going

Comment: Thanks I was planning on redesigning I just wanted the function to work